# Manual positioning from a float value in iOS

Tags: ios, floating-point, position, manual

I've currently got an item positioned using the following

```
CGRect torpfr = torp.frame;
torpfr.origin.x =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"torpx"];
torpfr.origin.y =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"torpy"];
torp.frame = torpfr;
```

Basically this creates and positions the button based upon floats stored under `torpx` and `torpy`.

Essentially I have one object (`torpfr`) at `torpx`, `torpy`, and I needg to draw a second object (let's assume `label1`) offset to the `Torpfr`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look here :
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html

you'ld find : 
CGRectOffset

A rectangle that is the same size as the source, but with its origin offset by dx units along the x-axis and dy units along the y-axis with respect to the source.

about animation, have a look here : [iOS - Moving a UITextField to a Different Position when a UIView Moves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217566/ios-moving-a-uitextfield-to-a-different-position-when-a-uiview-moves)

Comment: Any chance you could help me with how this looks? I find the apple references quite hard to get my head around.

Comment: follow the link  "iOS - Moving a UITextField to a Different Position when a UIView Moves", all you need is here. try something like that :     [UIView beginAnimations:@"returnView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];  
    torp.frame = CGRectOffset(torpfr,100.0,100.0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: I presume roughly CGRect CGRectOffset (
   CGRect ORIGINAL,
   CGFloat 50,
   CGFloat 50,
); and that would just draw it into place?

Comment: previous comment code is to replace torp.frame = torpfr; to have an animated view

Comment: I'll have a play with it later when I have chance to get at Xcode. Essentially I have one object (the torpfr here) at torpx, torpy, and I'm needing to draw a second object (let's assume label1) offset to the Torpfr.

Comment: here torpfr is a struct not an object. To create dynamicaly a label, all you have to do if to do : UILabel *label1 =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:youroffsetedRect];  and add label1 to the view. And as long you have a mac, you can get xcode for free with an internet account on Apple's developper site.

Comment: I actually have label1 created in IB already and linked appropriately, is there not a way to define it's position directly related to the float's I've got stored? i.e. position it at torpx + 100? I fear that the solution presented above, whilst it'll work (pending testing!) seems more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: if label1 is an IBOutlet, all you need is to change it's frame : label1.frame = yourcomputedtoframe

Comment: so label1.frame = CGRectOffset(torpfr,100.0,100.0); ? I haven't got my Mac in front of me to test at the minute :)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - just had the time to try this and works a treat. Thank you for all your help.